# Understanding a proof of an Identity involving the Möbius Function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

**Lemma**: For each integer $N\geq 1$, we have

$$\sum_{(k,N)=1}\frac{t^k}{k}=-\sum_{d|N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}log(1-t^d)$$

**Proof.** Let $c_{k}=1$ if $(k,N)=1$ and $c_{k}=0$ otherwise. By basic propierties of the Möbius function we have $c_{k}=\sum_{d|(k,N)}\mu(d)$. Hence

$$\sum_{(k,N)=1}\frac{t^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k}$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|(k,N)}\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k}$$
$$=\sum_{d|N}\mu(d)\sum_{k\geq 1,\ d|k} \frac{t^k}{k} \ (\text{How can I do this?})$$
$$=\sum_{d|N}\mu(d)\sum_{k'=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{dk'}}{dk'}$$
$$=\sum_{d|N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\sum_{k'=1}^{\infty}\frac{(t^{d})^k}{k}$$
$$=-\sum_{d|N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}log(1-t^d)$$
This complete the proof of Lemma.

My question is How can I write

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|(k,N)}\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k}$$

in the form 
$$=\sum_{d|N}\mu(d)\sum_{k\geq 1,\ d|k} \frac{t^k}{k}$$?

Answer (score 1):

$d$ devides $k$ and $d$ divides $n$. Furthermore $\mu(d)$ does not depend on $k$, so we can just sum over $d \vert N$. For $t^k /k$ we have to sum from $k=1$ to $k = \infty$ but only for those $k$ that are divisible by $d$.

Comment: what do you mean by "d divides the tuple (k,N)"? Remmember that (k,N) means gratest common divisor

Comment: makes sense, didnt check the notation, sorry. If $ d$ devides the gcd of $k$ and $N$, then  $d$ surely devides  $k$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|(k,N)}\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k}$$
means the summ when your idices run over the set 
$$\{ (k, d) \mid 1 \leq k < \infty , d | (k,N) \}$$

Now,
$$\{ (k, d) \mid  1 \leq k < \infty , d | (k,N) \}=\{ (k, d)| 1 \leq k <\infty , d | k, d |N \}\\
=\{ (k, d)| d |N, 1 \leq k <\infty , d | k \}$$

Thus
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k}\\
=\sum_{ (k, d)| d |N, 1 \leq k <\infty , d | k }\left(\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k} \\
=\sum_{ d |N}\sum_{ 1 \leq k <\infty , d | k }\left(\mu(d)\right)\frac{t^k}{k} \\
=\sum_{ d |N}\left(\mu(d)\right) \left(\sum_{ 1 \leq k <\infty , d | k }\frac{t^k}{k}\right)
$$